# Dependency of the emulator on the windows graphics driver

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, directx

I'm using google android emulator on windows machine to run some of my OpenGL based graphics scenarios.
The scenarios use texture as the render target and create bitmaps from them and dump them as images.

I ran these scenarios on machine1 and generated a set of images - images1.
And then on machine2 and generated another set of images - images2.

images1 and images2 looks exactly same to the naked eye but when I compare the images pixel by pixel, there is a bit of difference.

Why would the images be different when the same emulators with same configurations are run on different machines? (Because of graphics driver version on windows machine?) 
How does emulator depend on the graphics driver of the machine?

Images become different(not to the naked eye) even on the same machine if I run scenarios after remotely logging into it.

Has anyone observed this and is there any way to configure emulator in a way that the underneath graphics driver dependency goes away?

I also changed the OpenGL ES Renderer to ANGLE(D3D11) in the emulator but still getting different images on different machines.

I want to understand how does emulator interact with the graphics driver so that I can fix this thing and get same images on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator graphics stack is just an API translator - turning OpenGL ES API calls into native graphics API calls on the host machine.

OpenGL and OpenGL ES are not specified to be bit-exact across implementations; 
differences are to expected on different GPUs and even different drivers for the same GPU. This is not a bug.